# How to force to return in time swift 3

Tags: multithreading, swift3, return

I am a newbie in swift language. The thing I want to ask is, why return works before the body of function? For example:
If I have a function

```
func somefunc(completion: @escaping ([String]){
 let something = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
 completion(something)
}

func appending() -> Int {
 var somestring = [String]()
    somefunc { (result) in
     for i in 0..<result.count{
       somestring.append(result[i])
      }
    }
 return somestring.count
}
```

So, in that case function appending() will return 0. However I want it should be 5. Return works before the somefunc will append the result to variable i. How to set them order? Or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but `func somefunc(completion: @escaping ([String]) { ... }` still makes no sense. Nor does `self.` in `self.somestring` inside `appending`. Nor does use of `let` in `let somestring = ...`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me explain you why I am asking this. I am using json and I have to take the value or result which I receive from the server, then after this return should work. But return works before the value comes from the server, and my cell is becoming empty.

Comment: Fine, but you've got to give us a reproducible example, which this isn't. More than likely, your method that has `@escaping` closure is actually doing something asynchronous (which your example is not). Let's ignore your example for a second and focus on methods with something that's really an asynchronous `@escaping` closure, the bottom line is that you cannot just plan on "returning" the result immediately. The entire idea behind `@escaping` is that you use it when the function happens so slowly that you're consciously saying "this will be called later", well after this function returns.

Comment: okay, I understand your idea) But how to say "hey 'return', please wait when my data fills (somestring), then after this work" - in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's set aside your `somefunc` method, which we might infer from presence of `@escaping`, is trying to do something asynchronously. Clearly, in your attempt to simplify the question, you've converted it to something that isn't asynchronous. But let's assume it really was calling its completion handler closure asynchronously (i.e. later) on the main thread. You could then do something like:

```
var stringsForTable = [String]()

func appending() {
    somefunc { results in
        self.stringsForTable.append(contentsOf: results)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Note, `appending` isn't returning anything, because you can't return data from an asynchronous function (because asynchronous functions don't call their completion handler closures until later, until well after `appending` has finished). But what `appending` *can* do is trigger whatever you need for your UI to be reloaded when the completion handler is called.

This is just a hypothetical example, but it illustrates the pattern. We'd have to see what `somefunc` is actually doing to advise further.

Comment: Oh thank you))) The thing I had to do is just to reloadData :D. Thank you once more)